# Printing extra comma in while loop - Python

Tags: python-3.x, printing

I don't want to print the last comma in my loop.

```py
countWhile = 5
while countWhile > 0:
    if countWhile == 0:
        break
    else:
        print(countWhile, end=', ')
    countWhile -= 1
print("While Loop Finished.")
```

Actual result: 5, 4, 3, 2, 1,

Expected result: 5, 4, 3, 2, 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one possible solution:

```
countWhile = 5
myList = []
while countWhile > 0:
    if countWhile == 0:
        break
    else:
        myList.append(str(countWhile))
    countWhile -= 1
print(', '.join(myList))
print("While Loop Finished.")
```

I can try to look for another simpler one if you want.